# backbone-tastypie: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

I am trying to use Backbone with Django.

I first took the working local example of Backbone from todomvc:
https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/master/architecture-examples/backbone

I then wanted to use the server instead of the local storage.
So I chose django-tastypie for the REST API.
I tested the REST API with a REST client (postman) in my browser and it works.

I then wanted to make it work with the todomvc example.
I set up a few things to use the server and not the local storage.
I got the small conversion layer backbone-tastypie.js as everybody recommends. (https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie/blob/master/backbone_tastypie/static/js/backbone-tastypie.js)

However, I get a **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** when I use the fetch method on my collection when I use the backbone-tastypie.js layer.

Any idea?

More details on the error:

```
a = window.App
a.Todos.fetch()
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
arguments: Array[0]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
concat: function concat() { [native code] }
constructor: function Array() { [native code] }
every: function every() { [native code] }
filter: function filter() { [native code] }
forEach: function forEach() { [native code] }
indexOf: function indexOf() { [native code] }
join: function join() { [native code] }
lastIndexOf: function lastIndexOf() { [native code] }
length: 0
map: function map() { [native code] }
pop: function pop() { [native code] }
push: function push() { [native code] }
reduce: function reduce() { [native code] }
reduceRight: function reduceRight() { [native code] }
reverse: function reverse() { [native code] }
shift: function shift() { [native code] }
slice: function slice() { [native code] }
some: function some() { [native code] }
sort: function sort() { [native code] }
splice: function splice() { [native code] }
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
unshift: function unshift() { [native code] }
__proto__: Object
get message: function () { [native code] }
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
set message: function () { [native code] }
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
stack: undefined
type: "stack_overflow"
__proto__: Error
arguments: undefined
constructor: function RangeError() { [native code] }
name: "RangeError"
stack: undefined
type: undefined
__proto__: SetUpError.d
```

Comment: What does your code look like? There's probably an infinite loop hiding somewhere.

Comment: Mu is probably right. From my (limited) experience with tastypie, an Maximum Call Stack size exceeded results from an infinite loop -- and often this is populating embedded resources in your tastypie code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did not have access to the internet anymore. I was actually trying to adapt the backbone example of todomvc to use the server instead of a local storage: https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/master/architecture-examples/backbone

Answer (score 0):

In your resources, do you have something like :

```
class MyResource1(ModelResource):
    attr1 = fields.ForeignKey('app.api.MyResource2', 'attr1', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = bla bla
        .
        .
        .

 class MyResource2(ModelResource):
       attr2 = fields.ForeignKey('app.api.MyResource1', 'attr2', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = bla bla
        .
        .
        .
```